# How to update an object which exists in another module in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I've broken down my source code so that certain classes are responsible for creating and updating key objects in my application. The trouble is when I move those objects into separate modules and they are updated outside of the module, other modules do not reflect the updated object because it's not aware of the changes which have happened outside of the module.

For example below is a simplified example:

```js
// config.js

class Config {
  constructor() {
    this.value = false
  }
  set(value) {
    this.value = value
  }
}

const config = new Config()

export default config
```

```js
//output.js

import config from './config'

console.log(config.value) // -> false

// Use the config to return a new value
class Output {
  constructor() {
    this.data = config.value
  }
}

const output = new Output()

export default output
```

```js
//index.js

import config from './config'
import output from './output'

config.set(true) // Value set by user of application

console.log(config.value) // -> true
console.log(output.data) // -> false
```

I know why this doesn't work as I want, but I don't know how to I should be dealing with this situation. Currently, the only way I can think to get around this issue is to pass the updated object to each class as a parameter of its constructor. However, in my actual application, it's much more complicated than this example and it gets very messy having to import the updated object into each class or function which needs it.

You can see an example of the [actual source code](https://github.com/limitlessloop/mole/blob/version-3/src/lib/Output.js) where I am passing `config`, `theme` and `data` through the constructor to get around it.

What's the better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: `this.data = config.value` this line is your problem. `config.value` is a boolean, which is copied by value on write. It doesn't hold the reference to the config object. This has nothing to do with imports/exports. Also please don't used reserved key words as method names, that's asking for trouble.

Comment: I realise that this isn't exclusive to imports and exports, but I didn't know how else to explain my situation (because when all in one file the problem doesn't necessarily show itself). How should I be correctly referencing the config object? Thanks for the advice about avoiding using reserved keywords as method names.

Comment: see FullStackGuy's answer. The thing is, just like pretty much every other language, in Javascript you have primitive types (undefined, strings, numbers, booleans, symbols) and reference types (everything else like arrays, objects, etc). When you make an assignment like `let foo = x`  if x evaluates to a primitive type the value of foo is determined on *assignment* (write). But if x is a reference type, then foo is a reference to x and what value foo has is determined when it is *dereferenced* (read). And it doesn't matter if it's x or x.someProperty, the same rules apply.

Answer (score 3):

In your `output.js` file, you are copying the value of `config.value` in the constructor when the object is instantiated. After the instantiation you are exporting the object initialized with `false`.

Now in the `index.js` you are accessing the value of `output.data` after you changed the `value` property in `config` to `true`, but the thing is when the `output` object was instantiated the value of the `data` property was copied over from the `config.value` and does not maintain a reference to it. This is because the `value` is a primitive and not an object reference.

So to fix this you need to use the `config` object reference which is already imported in your module, so that when the object state is changed you get the updated value through the reference:

```
import config from './config.js'

class Output {
  get data(){
    return config.value;
  }
}
```

Here I created a getter having the name `data` which reads the data directly from the `config` object *reference*.

Now when you change the `value` through the `set` method of `config` the new value would be reflected:

```
config.set(true);

console.log(config.value) // -> true
console.log(output.data) // -> true
```

Comment: you don't have to add `config` to a class instance since it's already in scope and can be accessed through `config.value`

Comment: @marzelin oh my how can I miss the `import`! you're right, let me update that right away!

Comment: Thanks very much for showing me that. I knew that there was an issue with the way the object was instantiating a value which didn't maintain a reference to it, but I couldn't explain as clearly as you have. I would like to maintain the source code for using the updated config value, inside the `output.js` module, therefore from your example, I have concluded that I will need to call the getter `output.data`, when `config.set(true)` is called (inside the Config class set method). This will mean I'll need to import the instance of `output` into `config.js` as well. Is this an ok practice?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with an example. I've commented out where the imports would be if there were in separate files. https://jsfiddle.net/6emxbzkg/2/